# Waiting for $.post answer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm checking if the entered login is already registered in my database using ajax function below...

```
function freelog(login) {
    var data = {login:login};
    $.post ('freelog.php', data, function(response){
            if(response == '1') {
                freelogin = true;
            } else if(response == '0') {
                freelogin = false;
            } else {
                freelogin =  response;
            }
    });
    return freelogin;
}
```

Of course I have a problem with the line:

```
return freelogin;
```

The reason is that $.post need some time to answer... I have no idea how to solve this prroblem... Hope, You'll help me :)

Comment: I guess, this is the most asked question on ajax :)

Comment: @Jashwant yes.  Second most-asked question is about binding event handlers in a loop :-)

Comment: Since sync ajax is nasty and you might not always want to write in the callback style, have a look at http://tamejs.org/ - however, in a browser environment it requires you to preprocess your JS files. But since you are probably minifying your production code anyway this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have your "freelog()" function return a value, as you've figured out, so instead have it accept a second argument. That should be a function to call when the response is available.

```
function freelog(login, callback) {
    var data = {login:login};
    $.post ('freelog.php', data, function(response){
            if(response == '1') {
                freelogin = true;
            } else if(response == '0') {
                freelogin = false;
            } else {
                freelogin =  response;
            }
            callback( freelogin );
    });
}
```

The asynchronous nature of the JavaScript browser environment tends to drive all APIs toward that form.

*edit* — calling your function, then, would look something like:

```
  freelog( username, function( isOk ) {
    if ( isOk ) {
      // put a big green check mark next to the username field
    }
    else {
      alert("That user name is taken");
    }
  }
```

or whatever.

Comment: The perfect and the cleanest way +1 :)

Comment: Given this is for a login, switching to a synchronous ajax request would be appropriate as well - can't do anything until the login attempt returns anyways.

Comment: Well, freezing the whole UI might be a little drastic; there could be other form fields being filled out for which client-side validation should proceed.

Comment: It would be better if you can show, how to call the function freelog :)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is such a pain, in that the benefits of asynchronocity also has it's drawback (at least until we think of it as the norm).

You need to return the result in the callback, not just set the variable, which, as you discovered, has no value since the ajax is still being tended to. Here's one example of how to change your code easily:

```
function freelog(login) {
    var data = {login:login};
    $.post ('freelog.php', data, function(response){
            if(response == '1') {
                freelogin = true;
            } else if(response == '0') {
                freelogin = false;
            } else {
                freelogin =  response;
            }
            return freelogin;
    });
}
```

All I did was move the return to within the post callback, so it won't get returned until the request is done. As advised by others, it is better to get more sophisticated and have things like:

1. A spinner or "checking" or some kind of feedback, assuming the request takes longer than a millisecond.
2. Having the `freelogin` actually return something meaningful.  Assuming it's being called by another function that is awaiting the response to output "Not available" you should be fine, but if you are just outputting the `freelogin` or have some code that depends right away on the response, you'll need to further revamp to get your script asynchronous.

Last bit of advice, here's a nice way to tighten up that callback function:

```
$.post ('freelog.php', data, function(response){
            return (Number(response) <= 1) ? Boolean(Number(response)) : response;
    });
```